# Removing a Gmail account on a computer I'm selling

Tags: macos, gmail

How do I remove a Gmail account in Apple Mail on a computer I am giving away? I do use IMAP and want to make sure I don't lose any of my emails on my other computer and iPad.

Comment: If you are giving the computer away I would do more than remove the email - I would at least remove the user and delete all its data, or better reformat, reinstall the OS.

Comment: Check out http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/53995 and http://support.apple.com/kb/ht4718

Answer (score 4):

All you need to do is remove that account from the Mac you intend to sell and all your emails will subsequently be deleted *from that Mac* and no other devices will be affected. To remove the account:

1. Open Mail Preferences (<kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>,</kbd> or Mail -> Preferences)
2. Select "Accounts"
3. Select the account(s) that you wish to remove, and proceed to select the minus button below the list of accounts.
4. Accept the prompt by clicking "Remove".

[image: Mail Preferences]