# Reinstalling OSX is blocked with unreviewed Apple ID

Tags: macos, apple-id, install

I got a couple-of-years-old MacBook Pro with OSX Lion, and I attempted to format it. I erased the installed drive using Disk Utilities and then chose to reinstall OSX.

Unfortunately, in order to reinstall, I had to enter Apple ID. I, of course, have an Apple ID, but when I enter it, I get a prompt dialog asking to review the account. Clicking it, nothing happens. Of course I don't have the original Apple ID of the original owner.

Is there any way to bypass this in order to reinstall? I'm currently completly stuck.

Comment: It depends on the OS that shipped with the MacBook. OS installs are tied to the serial number and not an account, so you might have to narrow that down first before troubleshooting the account in question.

Comment: @bmike how can I find that out?

Answer (score 1):

AppleCare often will provide help for locating a manual that will have the installation steps for free, so you could start there.

If you wanted to DIY - here are some items to check:

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204319 - lists the versions for OS shipped with various Mac
- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201300 - how to identify MacBook pro models

From there, you could see if you need to reorder physical media or if the App Store should let you boot to internet recovery or a recovery HD for reinstallation or if you need to get a bootable installer made on another Mac.

- https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/16560/5472
- [Reinstalling Lion](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/53995/reinstalling-lion)